# "Reflecting" addition

Tags: haskell, integer

I'm implementing the following function for signed integer numbers: given endpoints of a closed interval `lo` and `hi`, and inputs `x` (in `[lo..hi]`) and `dx`, I'd like to compute the "reflected sum": 
if `x + dx` is still in `[lo..hi]` then that's it; otherwise the underhanging or overhanging portion is "folded back" onto the result (shown as `y` below). Basically, `x` is "bouncing around" in the interval.

```
                             overhang
                             /--\
                     dx
                 -------------->
--------[-------|-------|---]---|------
       lo       x       y   hi  x + dx
                        <---
```

Because this is for a hardware circuit, I am doing this using Clash's [sized `Signed` integer type](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/clash-prelude-1.0.1/docs/Clash-Sized-Signed.html) and [width-extending addition](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/clash-prelude-1.0.1/docs/Clash-Class-Num.html#v:add), otherwise it is normal Haskell code.

My current implementation is the following:

```
bounce :: (KnownNat n, KnownNat k, (k + 1) <= n) => (Signed n, Signed n) -> Signed n -> Signed k -> (Signed n, Bool)
bounce (lo, hi) x dx
    | under > 0 = (lo + under, True)
    | over > 0 = (hi - over, True)
    | otherwise = (resize new, False)
  where
    new = add x dx
    under = resize $ resize lo - new
    over = resize $ new - resize hi
```

Things I don't like about this implementation:

- There is a lot of noise about bit widths (all the `resize` calls)
- Overall, it is not immediately obvious by just looking at the code what it does. It feels like it's doing a lot of seemingly ad-hoc arithmetic operations that "just happen" to work.

I am looking for improvements that come from the structure of the problem, not "oh you should rename `x` to `theNumberThatIsBouncingAround` because one-letter variable names bad".

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your code agrees with your spec: Your code looks like it can only implement a function built from three line segments.

You shouldn't need explicit resize.

```
bounce (lo, hi) x dx = let
  (bounces, remainder) = divMod (add dx $ x-lo) $ hi-lo
  in (if even bounces then lo + remainder else hi - remainder
     ,bounces /= 0)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `divMod` by a non-power-of-two is not really implementable as a combinational circuit.

Comment: I'm happy with not supporting multiple bounces in one timestep.

Comment: You are already implementing `divMod` by means of a lookup table for div in {-1,0,1}. That's why your code looks improvable to you. You do in fact need to implement `divMod` in some way, for that is your problem statement.